# What is this TMCacheDelete log sequence?

Tags: backup, time-machine, time-capsule, macos

I have a number of external drives used for Time Machine backups, including a Time Capsule. Since installing Sierra, backups to the TC have been significantly slower (e.g., 16 hours for a 2GB backup). Upon exploring the logs (and filtering on "backup"), I see a lot of TMCacheDelete messages, usually 8 or so triplets of, each 8-triplet sequence occurring every 3 seconds.

> default    10:40:19.147281 -0700   TMCacheDelete   < private >
>   default    10:40:19.147322 -0700   TMCacheDelete   Skipping entitlement
>      check...
>   default    10:40:19.151540 -0700   TMCacheDelete   newConnection
>      invalidated

This occurs whether it is a TC or a directly attached drive, and it also occurs when all the drives are removed/disabled from Time Machine Preferences, and "Back Up Automatically" (newly renamed in Sierra) unchecked.

Thoughts on this sequence of log messages, or on its relation with slow backups?